# CodeIgniter and Google Calendar API

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, google-calendar-api

I have a problem understanding client_id in Google API development environment. In every application this configuration as the app developer is required :

```
 $client->setClientId('YOUR CLIENT ID');
 $client->setClientSecret('YOUR CLIENT SECRET');
 $client->setRedirectUri('YOUR REDIRECT URI');
 $client->setDeveloperKey('API/DEVELOPER KEY');
```

And I know how to obtain these parameters. So , I developed a simple Google calendar API and I wanted to use " get events list" method :

```
$cal = new Google_CalendarService($client);
    if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
       unset($_SESSION['token']);
    }
....
....
....

$events = $cal->events->listEvents('CALENDAR_ID');
print_r($events, true);
```

Now , in line " $events = $cal->events->listEvents('CALENDAR_ID');" if i put my email address instead of "CALENDAR_ID" , it will work properly and it will list my event, but if I log in with a different Gmail account ( which will prompt me to authenticate ), it will generate an error, basically this "CALENDAR_ID" replaces the email address , so if its the developer himself, it will work, but not the new login. So how do I get the other Gmail account's CALENDAR_ID to insert in there ? If I can't get the other account's CALENDAR_ID after its authenticated , what would be this application any good if it only works with My OWN ( developer) CALENDAR_ID ? 
Please advise
Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you heard of code formatting?

Comment: I'm very new here, just learning how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "primary" keyword instead of the email address.